# How to improve the regex?

Tags: php, regex, pcre

I'm trying to match the following possibilities with a regex:

```
MORE THAN CAD 10,000
MORE THAN CAD 10,000 BUT LESS THAN CAD 15,000
LESS THAN CAD 10,000
```

My regex works with `/^(((MORE|LESS) THAN CAD [\d,]+)|(MORE THAN CAD [\d,]+ BUT LESS THAN CAD [\d,]+))$/` but I'm wondering if there's a more elegant way.

I've tried `/^(MORE THAN CAD [\d,]+)?(( BUT )?LESS THAN CAD [\d,]+)?$/` but it's letting the following pass as well:

```
MORE THAN CAD 10,000LESS THAN CAD 15,000
```

Comment: Like `^(?:MORE|LESS) THAN CAD \d[\d,]*(?: BUT LESS THAN CAD \d[\d,]*)?$`? Using an optional group?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew But that will allow `LESS THAN CAD 10,000 BUT LESS THAN CAD 10,000` to pass.

Comment: What is the programming language? You might use `^(?:(MORE)|LESS) THAN CAD [\d,]+(?(1)(?: BUT LESS THAN CAD [\d,]+)?)$` if conditionals are supported

Comment: Chin, is it PCRE in PHP?

Comment: Yeah it's PCRE in PHP @WiktorStribiżew

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```php
^(?:(MORE)|LESS) THAN CAD [\d,]+(?(1)(?: BUT LESS THAN CAD [\d,]+)?)$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/67tTUv/1).

*Details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `(?:(MORE)|LESS)` - a non-capturing group matching `MORE` (captured in Group 1) or `LESS`
- `THAN CAD`  - a literal string
- `[\d,]+` - one or more digits or commas
- `(?(1)(?: BUT LESS THAN CAD [\d,]+)?)` - a conditional that allows matching an optional  `BUT LESS THAN CAD [\d,]+` pattern if Group 1 matched.
- `$` - end of string.